# Skype For Business Server 2019 - Better way to Integrate the Chat Bots with server 2019

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am trying to integrate A Chat Bot Service with A client who uses the Skype For Business Server 2019. On Microsoft Docs Page, I found that [UCWA 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) exposes SFB Server 2015 instant messaging (IM) and presence capabilities. Could anyone please confirm whether this holds good for SFB Server 2019?

Do we have any better way to integrate the Bots with SFB Server 2019 other than UCWA 2.0 (As I came across the docs that mentioned UCWA having IM limitations and scaling issues)?

From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), Bot Framework also deprecated the support for Skype or business channel.

Please provide any information you have regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that UCWA will scale just fine, I know of some projects for pretty large organisations that have used it.

As an alternative you could look at UCMA 6.0 (which is more feature complete than UCWA), this is the SFB 2019 release and whilst I haven't seen any explicit documentation for this version I very much doubt it has changed much since UCMA 5.0 as the Microsoft strategy at the time of release was focused on Teams.

Answer (score 0):

There’s 3rd party software available that can help with this, check out [MindLink](https://www.mindlinksoft.com/integrations). Their API supports various versions of SfB server and I believe 2019 is covered too. You can apply throttling and other management capabilities so it is built to scale - it could be more for the enterprise, then again I don’t know what your project is.